# App engine versions

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, lwip

I use Google App Engine for me nodejs project. Today I tried deploy the new version, but app engine throw error. After that I tried deploy the previous version (worked in past), steel throw error.

I do not understand it. It worked before, but now doesn't. The new version of App Engine?  Could you help me please?

In log I see problem with **lwip** library. After remove it works, but I need the library.

> In file included from ../src/lib/png/png.c:14:0:
>     ../src/lib/png/pngpriv.h:805:4: error: #error ZLIB_VERNUM !=  PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM "-I (include path) error: see the notes in pngpriv.h"
>    #  error ZLIB_VERNUM != PNG_ZLIB_VERNUM \
>       ^
>   lwip_decoder.target.mk:165: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/lwip_decoder/src/lib/png/png.o' failed

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using App Engine Standard or Flex Environment? 
Did the original version of your app include lwip library while deploying?

Comment: It's because of your node version. You need v6.10.1 or lower. See here: https://github.com/EyalAr/lwip/issues/297

Comment: Claudio has contributed a potential answer. OP, you should look into it and let us know if that resolved it.